# Possible to use the Notion API to create Twitter embeds on a page, from a csv list?

Tags: javascript, notion-api

I have a .csv file with a column of many links to Twitter, like this:

> URL
> https://twitter.com/WIRED/status/1431940938981597195
> https://twitter.com/theQuietus/status/1431896907006234626
> https://twitter.com/BloombergAsia/status/1431896671340961796
>
> …

I want to import all tweets into Notion as Tweet embeds (`/tweet` command) on a page.

I attempted using the unofficial solution [`notion-py`](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py) for this, but could not get even the [Quickstart](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py#quickstart) example to work (`raise HTTPError(requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Invalid input.`)

Is it possible to use the Notion API for this objective?

Or would you advise some other solution?

I haven't used Notion API, nor do I have much experience with JavaScript. But if you know that it's possible to accomplish this task via Notion API, or may have an example, I would be very happy.